# What is a good resource for learning equivalent JSP, JSTL tags/EL, and Struts tags?

Tags: jsp, struts, el

I'm looking to separate business logic from presentation in a project, but the business logic is written using a mixture of tag libraries. Are there any good resources for going from one taglib to another, converting Scriptlet code to EL and back, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Scoping - EL, Struts Tags, JSP Equivalent forms](http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/struts.html#Struts-and-JSTL)
Particularly in "Using the JSP 2.0 Expression Language with Jakarta Struts"

[Logic and Bean Tags - Related JSTL Mechanisms](http://jaist.dl.sourceforge.net/project/struts/Struts%20Atlanta%20Presentations/05_29_03%20-%20Bill%20Siggelkow/jstl-and-struts.pdf) (Page 28,29)

[Struts Logic Tag attribute descriptions](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wsadhelp/v5r1m2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.etools.struts.doc/topics/rstrdoc019.html)
[Struts Bean Tag attribute descriptions](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wsadhelp/v5r1m2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.etools.struts.doc/topics/rstrdoc011.html)

The Struts documentation on struts.apache.org also lists JSTL equivalents for a few tags, as well as descriptions of tag attributes, but I personally found it to be less than thorough on the former, and less readable than the IBM documentation on the latter.

Answer (score 1):

Head First Servlets and JSP by Bates & Sierra is good.